# Print array lenght with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to print a list in which every entry should look like "element X of TOTAL" but instead of TOTAL i get only blank text.
I fell like it's something stupid but i can't figure out what.
This is from my html

```
<li ng-repeat="elem in lista" ng-show="check">
    Elemento {{elem.item}} di {{len}}
    <button ng-click="remove(elem)">Remove</button>
</li>
```

and here is from my app.js, which includes my controller

```
$scope.lista = [
        { item: 'uno' },
        { item: 'due' },
        { item: 'tre' }
];

var len = $scope.lista.lenght;
```

Comment: Elemento {{elem.item}} di {{lista.length}}

Comment: tried without success

Comment: I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.  Every answer here is duplicating the incorrect spelling of `length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var len = $scope.lista.lenght;
```

To :

```
$scope.len = $scope.lista.length;
```

Comment: tried without success

Comment: Delete var len = $scope.lista.lenght; 
And change {{len}} to {{lista.length}}

Comment: Still nothing. This is fustrating

Comment: I checked at my place and it works. Show me your all controller in angular.
This is work fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/17258/

Comment: too long for a comment, here is a link https://pastebin.com/b8QWzPfy

Comment: Did you check my fiddle? You have $scope.check = false; in your controller, but your HTML you have ng-show="check", so $scope.check should be true, not false

Comment: Ok, I see your mistake. You have lengHT, should be LENGTH.
Check my edit answer

Comment: i want to kill me. regarding your first comment, that is just a boolean check, so it can be true or false (there is a button to show the list or to hide it) 
Anyway, thank you